# Start sample 0009 in WSO2 CEP sample mode

Tags: wso2, hex, wso2-cep

I am trying to try out the sample 0009 in WSO2 CEP. It is for a MAP event in JMS protocol.

When i am trying to run WSO2 CEP in the sample mode i execute the following command in windows to run the sample in samples/cep/artifacts:

wso2cep-samples.bat -sn 0009

which results in the following error:
Invalid Number. Numeric constants are either decimal (17), hexadecimal (0x11) or octal (021). 
0 was expected at this time.

Although, when i run the sample mode for 0011 no error of that sort is displayed.

I am using WSO2 CEP version 4.2.0

I tried looking for an already open bug but there is none. Anyone faced a similar issue?

EDIT: if i run the same ocmmand with 0011 and stop it after it starts i can run the command with the 0009 but still displays that error message in the beginning of the execution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that error is batch will interpret '0009' as octal (because in batch scripting leading zero will specify Octal) and '0009' is an invalid Octal.

To get rid of this error, edit `wso2cep-samples.bat` file and comment out line 48 & 49 like below, and then try to run the sample using `wso2cep-samples.bat -sn 0009`

```
rem SET /A UserInputVal="%cn%"*1
rem IF %UserInputVal% EQU 0 GOTO invalid_number
```